# iOS6 - UICollectionViewFlowLayout doesn't place the cell correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I added a UICollectionView with a frame size 320x600, with each item size 44x44. The final output doesn't correctly position the cells in every row. There are some cells are positioned outside the bound of collection view, it would look like the image in this link: http://cl.ly/image/2s270g1p1g2e

The #4, #5, #6, #11, #12, #13, and else are outside the bound of collection view. And here is my code of my initiate of UICollectionView and flow layout:

```
SSCalendarFlowLaout *flowlayout = [[SSCalendarFlowLaout alloc] init];
flowlayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0f;
flowlayout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0f;
flowlayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(44, 44);
flowlayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600);
self.calendarGrids = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:rect
                                          collectionViewLayout:flowlayout];
self.calendarGrids.delegate = self;
self.calendarGrids.dataSource = self;

self.calendarGrids.allowsSelection = YES;
self.calendarGrids.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

[self.calendarGrids registerClass:[SSCalendarDayCell class]
         forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CalendarDayCell"];

[self addSubview:self.calendarGrids];
```

SSCalendarFlowLayout is a subclass from UICollectionViewFlowLayout. The reason to subclass it is to debug this issue:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {

  NSArray *unfilteredPoses = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
  for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *pose in unfilteredPoses) {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(pose.frame));
  }
  return unfilteredPoses;
}
```

And interestingly, the output of layoutAttributesForElementsInRect for each item is correct, like below console output:

```
2012-11-12 23:42:59.275 Calendar[49367:c07] {{0, 22}, {44, 44}}
2012-11-12 23:42:59.275 Calendar[49367:c07] {{55.2, 22}, {44, 44}}
2012-11-12 23:42:59.276 Calendar[49367:c07] {{110.4, 22}, {44, 44}}
2012-11-12 23:42:59.278 Calendar[49367:c07] {{165.6, 22}, {44, 44}}
2012-11-12 23:42:59.278 Calendar[49367:c07] {{220.8, 22}, {44, 44}}
2012-11-12 23:42:59.279 Calendar[49367:c07] {{276, 22}, {44, 44}}
2012-11-12 23:42:59.279 Calendar[49367:c07] {{0, 76}, {44, 44}}
```

But why the output is so different to the frame set from UICollectionViewFlowLayout? The output are both wrong in simulator and iPhone.

I suspected it is a related bug with this one: http://openradar.appspot.com/12433891
But unlike this bug, UICollectionViewFlowLayout misplaces cells in each row, not just the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I misset the rect of label inside the cell. I added a subview of UILabel in each cell, but what happened in this problem is I configure the label like below:

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {

    self.dayLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.dayLabel];

  }
  return self;

}
```

which is definitely wrong. I correct the frame set as: self.dayLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){CGPointZero, frame.size}];
Then everything works correctly.
Thanks anyway